# Why are message templates not appearing when I email a contact?

Tags: civimail

I upgraded a client system from 4.4.12 to 4.5.8 at the weekend and now message templates are not appearing when a user creates an email (regular or bulk).  You can pick a template but nothing appears.  In Administer/CiviMail/Message Templates all the templates are there, and can be edited & saved. My other upgrades to 4.5.8 have not shown this problem so I am puzzled - I've cleared the Drupal caches and CiviCRM caches.

Comment: I meant upgrade from 4.4.12 to 4.5.8, sorry for confusion!  Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a javascript problem. You could either [troubleshoot it yourself](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850.0.html) or just upgrade to the latest version of CiviCRM which has a rewritten CiviMail interface anyway and so the problem is unlikely to be in the new version.

Comment: I tried upgrading to 4.6.2 and the new CiviMail interface didn't even load, so that was not good. Oddly the problem of message templates not loading appeared to be fixed in the new release, but after about 15-20 minutes the problem re-appeared. I restored back to 4.4.12 and it's all working now.

Comment: @AndyClark it sounds like your website has some (at least one) fairly serious js problems going on. If the new CiviMail doesn't even load, that is not good indeed. But downgrading Civi isn't IMO the solution because the problem is most likely not coming from Civi. Until you fix the js bugs on your website you will continue experiencing subtle and not-so-subtle problems with Civi whenever it tries to do stuff with js. The symptoms will indeed be more obvious in newer versions of Civi because it uses more js, but the underlying problem is the same.

Comment: Well I agree going back is not ideal, but we had emails to get out.  We have another problem on this server with Civicrm-webform not working.  Contacts added get to webform (ie. show up in 'tracking') but don't get into Civi.  Could this also be js?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a javascript problem. Use your browser development console to to check for a jQuery error on the page due to a theme / block / other module conflict problem.

Comment: Yes, we have seen the message 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined'.  Any thoughts on what do next?  I raised issue CRM-16509 but it can't be reproduced on the sandbox so no progress there.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for my issue: the Pogstone Module (drupal) was in direct conflict. Removing that module has fixed the issue.